# Concatenation two Video clip

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to concatenate two video clips with the following code:

```
import moviepy
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
file1 = 'IMG_3591.MOV'
file2 = 'IMG_3592.MOV'
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([file1,file2],method="compose")
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4")
```

However, I'm getting the  following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duration'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `concatenate_videoclips()` needs to be a list of `VideoClip` objects, not a list of strings.

Try this:

```
import moviepy
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

file1 = VideoFileClip('IMG_3591.MOV')
file2 = VideoFileClip('IMG_3592.MOV')
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([file1,file2], method="compose")
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4")
```

Comment: Thanks its work two video clip concatenate but Video quality is very bad . Is there way to avoid poor Video quality after concatenate

Comment: That's another question and I have no idea sorry.